# is it possible to display progress bar switching between one activity to another activity in android

Tags: android, progress-bar

Is it possible to show progress bar when switching from activity to another.please help me

Answer (score 0):

You will have to show the progress bar in the second activity because the first activity will be hidden and wouldn't show up anyway.

Comment: I am  calling API in second Activity so it takes time in loading. so How to add progress bar in second Activitybefore API call or after ?

Answer (score 0):

try this!!!!

ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(FirstActivity.this);

//use this before calling intent

pd.setMessage("Processing...");

pd.show();

//call this in onResume of firstActivity

pd.dismiss();